# How to setup HPC cluster on one server

Tags: virtual-machine, cluster-computing, provisioning, hpc

i'm working on an application that needs to be tested in a HPC cluster.
i'm thinking about using xcat as a resource manager.
i don't have much hardware resources, i have one HP desktop and MacBook laptop.
the question: is it possible to set up a virtual cluster (using virtualBox or KVM) on **one hardware resource**

thanks,

Comment: Yes, you can do with virtualization technology; however, you will spend substantial time to setup it correctly (esp network). If you want to study setup/management, aws is a very cheap option.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you support me with useful links that can help set up this?

Comment: @DalalAlghomlas, please, give us details on your application. What kind of HPC it uses? Is it OpenMP, MPI or any other parallel library?

Comment: @xosp7tom, how it is possible to combine two separate computers connected only by (Ethernet/Wifi) network into single shared-memory virtual machine? Check his question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495315/is-it-possible-to-a-vcpu-to-use-different-cpus-from-two-different-hardware-compu

Comment: In short answer, impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer here is yes, depending on how much memory and disk you have available on your one machine. I've done this numerous times on a MacBook Pro with 8 GB of RAM.

The long answer is that there is absolutely nothing magical about an HPC cluster. All you need to test basic parallel applications in a simulated cluster environment are two or more VMs which meet these criteria:

1. Same OS, as identical as possible.
2. Passwordless authentication (ssh key based auth).
3. Same software stack in same location on all nodes (See #4 or use rsync).
4. At least one shared filesystem, e.g. NFS mounted $HOME
5. Shared network with name resolution configured (correct /etc/hosts on all nodes)

None of this requires job schedulers, provisioning tools or any complex networking. You can find many NFS setup howtos to help get one node set up to share $HOME to the others, this might be the most complicated part. VirtualBox does a good job of setting up local networking.

On top of this you can layer setting up a job scheduler like SLURM (highly recommended), provisioning tools like Warewulf or xCat, parallel filesystems across the VMs (BeeGFS is easy to set up and a great introduction), etc. I have had a full featured stateless cluster simulated on my Macbook Pro a number of times using tools from this list and VirtualBox VMs. It's a great way to learn about setting up an HPC cluster.